# How to remove only sub category URL from magento

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, url-modification

I am using Magento for my eCommerce website

My current URL structure is :

`example.com/parent-category/sub-category/page`

I want a solution for the URL be changed to:

`example.com/parent-category/page`

I just want to remove sub category from the URL

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about Magento should be asked on [magento.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 1):

We can configure it by URL Rewrites

1. Go to Magento 2 Admin -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites
2. Find the path by searching the Request path column.
3. Remove the cache PHP bin/magento cache:clean.
4. Refresh the front-end, click the main menu category then you can see the configured path.